# Guard Sass - gem file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, guard

I am using [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard-shell) to watch filesystem change and run some script. I am not familiar with ruby environment. So far, to use watcher, I only needed to install Shell (No gem file). Now, I am trying to add Sass as well, following the instruction [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-sass).

I installed it through 
`gem install guard-shell`

But, when try the next command
`gem 'guard-sass', :require => false`

it gives error

```
$ gem 'guard-sass', :require => false
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command guard-sass,
```

what is wrong? Do I need a gem file (not sure what should be the content, or why I need this)

```
guard list
+------------+--------------+
|  Available Guard plugins  |
+------------+--------------+
| Plugin     | In Guardfile |
+------------+--------------+
| Sass       | ✘          |
| Shell      | ✔          |
+------------+--------------+
```

Guardfile:

```
guard 'shell' do
  watch(/(.*).md/) {`python render.py` }
end
```

### EDIT:

skipping the bundler, gave this message. Not sure what are the implication, but `guard init sass` didn't add anything to my

```
    guard init sass
10:03:05 - INFO - Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running
> [#] `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free to ignore this
> [#] message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard` to ensure your
> [#] dependencies are loaded correctly.
> [#] (You can run `guard` with --no-bundler-warning to get rid of this message.)
10:03:05 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/sass' or '~/.guard/templates/sass' or find class Guard::Sass
```

Added a gemfile, and run like

```
bundle exec guard init sass
10:04:31 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/sass' or '~/.guard/templates/sass' or find class Guard::Sass
```

As mentioned above I installed sass

```
sudo gem install sass
```

and gemfile looks like:

## A sample Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
# gem "rails"
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem "sass"
  gem 'guard-sass', :require => false     
end
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
```

## EDIT 2:

It was permission issue, see https://github.com/hawx/guard-sass/issues/29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-read the guide on Github, you'll notice it says to add `gem 'guard-sass', :require => false` to your Gemfile, not run it in your terminal.

Now, if the documentation is correct, all you have to do it run `guard init sass`